# Require suggestions on how to handle custom 'contribution'

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, custom-fields

I run a large non-profit dog registration system.  One of the functions is to require all dogs to be registered with us for this particular sport.

The way I have it now, I have set up individual contacts and added custom, multiple entry custom fields.  Individuals need to purchase a dog registration.  I'm struggling with this setup since if the individual already has a dog registered, that dog info pops up in the form rather than it being blank.
The only way I can see charging for registration of dogs in this manner is through CiviContribute.  I would like:
1. Member accesses page to add a dog
2. Member enters dog info
3. Member enters payment info (I'm using iATS payment gateway)
4. On successful payment, the registration is completed.

Did I shoot myself in the foot by making these multiple custom fields under an individual?  I had heard some suggestions where the dogs should be a sub-class of an individual and then use a membership status to charge for them?
The issue with this is that there are way more fields then needed for a dog - how do I restrict which fields are visible on the backend for this type?

I'm looking for discussion and suggestions on this.  Any help is much appreciated.

Norm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think I can give you just one answer. IMO you need to try a few ways before you make your final decision. Memberships certainly sound like a good idea to try.

I can imagine dogs would be a contact subtype with their specific fields, and the registration should be a relationship between the individual (owner - perhaps also a contact subtype) and a dog.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you probably want to add the custom fields to the contribution record, that way every new registration will be a new contribution and the fields will be blank each time for the user